# Spring mongo how to retrieve data but newest date first

Tags: spring, spring-boot

How to I set my data when I retrieve it that the newest date will be first .At the moment when I retrieve it ist is newest date last. Tried order by but not managing

```
public class Notifications {
            @Id
            private String id;
            private String notificationMsg;
            private Date createdDate = new Date();

//Contructor
//Getter and Setter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this chunk of code, I hope it'll solve your problem <3

```
Query query = new Query();
query.with(new Sort(new Order(Direction.ASC, "createdDate").ignoreCase());
return mongoTemplate.find(query, Notifications.class);
```

Comment: Just what I needer (virtual high five, thank you :) )

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring-data with a `@Repository` annotation you can do this:

```
List<Notifications> findAllByOrderByCreateDateAsc();
```

Comment: Hi ,no im not using spring data